# How to remove duplicates in ListBox?

Tags: delphi, listbox, duplicates

I use this code to remove duplicates:

```
procedure TForm1.RemoveDuplicates(StrList : TStringList);
var   NoDuplicate: TStringList;
      i: Integer;
begin
  NoDuplicate := TStringList.Create;
  try
    NoDuplicate.Sorted := True;
    NoDuplicate.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
    ///
    for i := 0 to StrList.Count - 1 do
    NoDuplicate.Add(StrList[i]) ;
    ///
    NoDuplicate.Sorted:= False;
    StrList.Assign(NoDuplicate) ;
  finally
    NoDuplicate.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It works fine. But problem with "dupIgnore" is that it's not case-sensitive.
For example, "rodeo" & "Rodeo" for "dupIgnore" are duplicates, although they are not. How to fix this?

Comment: The best way to remove duplicates is to not allow duplicates to be added in the first place :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
NoDuplicate.CaseSensitive := True;
```

Comment: Simple as that... Thank you.